# Building an Angular 2 App with Clarity Design System

Tags: javascript, angular, systemjs, clarity, vmware-clarity

I'm getting this error after adding Clarity Design System from their official [tutorial](https://vmware.github.io/clarity/get-started/) to angular 2  [5min quickstart](https://github.com/angular/quickstart) . The error in browser's console doesn't help too much, any advice please?

```
zone.js:1382 GET http://localhost:3000/clarity-angular 404 (Not Found)
Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/clarity-angular(…)
```

app.module.ts

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {ClarityModule} from 'clarity-angular';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule,
            ClarityModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/clarity-icons/clarity-icons.min.css">
    <script src="node_modules/mutationobserver-shim/dist/mutationobserver.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/@webcomponents/custom-elements/custom-elements.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/clarity-icons/clarity-icons.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/clarity-ui/clarity-ui.min.css">

    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <my-app>Loading AppComponent content here ...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

systemjs.config.js

```
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',

      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/router/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router-upgrade.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',
      '@angular/upgrade/static': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade-static.umd.js',

      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js'

    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATED**
Add `clarity-angular` to `map` and `package` sections. See example below.

```
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/',
      'build:': 'build',
      'src:': ''
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      //app: 'build:',
      app: 'app',
      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',
      // other libraries
      'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
      //'angular2-mdl': 'npm:angular2-mdl/bundle/angular2-mdl.js'
      //'angular2-mdl': 'npm:angular2-mdl',
      'clarity-angular': 'npm:clarity-angular'
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: 'main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        main: 'Rx.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'clarity-angular': {
        main: 'index.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

If you are using Clarity directives directly in your main `app.component.html` you need to `import { ClarityModule } from 'clarity-angular';` and also add `ClarityModule` to `@NgModule imports`.
If you need to use Clarity directives under a Router you should also import `ClarityModule` in you application router module

```
import { NgModule }             from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { ClarityModule } from 'clarity-angular';

import { SearchFormComponent } from './components/search-form/search-form.component';

const routes: Routes = [
     { path: 'search', component: SearchFormComponent }
];
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        ClarityModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
    ],
    declarations: [
        SearchFormComponent
    ],
    exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: This `system.config` solved my problem. And `clr-datagrid` example from Clarity Project also works fine for me with yours code.

Comment: Great. Also pay attention to imports when you decide to introduce a Router NgModule into your application. You'll also need to import ClarityModule into the Router module.

Answer (score 0):

```
import {ClarityModule} from 'clarity-angular';
```

needs addition in systemjs.config for angular 2 latest version

Comment: could you tell me what exactly I have to add in systemjs.config.js? I've tried to add clarity-angular.min.js path to map section of config, but it didn't work